# Is it possible to sort by combinations?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my Code model, I coded a scope like this below.

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

It basically sorts by code.users.last_active_at at desc order.

It's working fine.
Now, I want to add extra condition to it.

If user.id=10000, I want to use code.created_at instead of code.user.last_active_at.
So the sort condition will be combination of
**code.created_at**
and
**code.users.last_active_at**

Is it possible? If so, how can I change my code?

Answer (score 1):

In Mysql you can use `CASE` statement, but no idea for the ruby but you can use your logic in pure query this way

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN user.id=10000
              THEN code.created_at
              ELSE code.users.last_active_at
         END
DESC
```